Can not get reply from RIGOL power supply command*IDN?
I want to automate a Rigol power supply. I have made the socket connection like this
import socket,os                 
ip= 1.2.3.4 #example
comport = int(os.environ["COM_SERVER_PORT_1"])

__socket_handler__ =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)        
__socket_handler__.connect((ip, comport))         
__socket_handler__.settimeout(0.5)                  
b_array = b"*IDN?"#\r\n"
__socket_handler__.send(b_array)  
buffer1 = __socket_handler__.recv(1024)

__socket_handler__.send(b_array)  
buffer2 = __socket_handler__.recv(1024)

                         

as buffer reply I always get buffer1 is b'\xff\xfd\x03\xff\xfd\x00\xff\xfd,' on buffer, the IDN command should ask for device ID and should get a reply any time is sent. In my case i get the above reply only once after the socket is created and not anymore, so buffer2 gets socket timeout.  The Device is Rigol power supply DP720. Does any body as a clue why this happens?
The commands send to the power supply have effect in that for example command: b":OUTPut:STATe CH1,ON" turns the power supply ON and comannd b":OUTPut:STATe CH1,OFF" turns it off an so on. But the power supply provides no reply for example to MEASure:VOLTage? CH1", so communication only works one way.  Thanks
I have looked online and on the Rigol Manuals and this posts but no use:
https://forums.ni.com/t5/FieldPoint-Family/Serial-device-responds-to-IDN-but-not-the-commands-that-should/m-p/701844
Cannot connect to a specific Ethernet port using Python and PyVisa
https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Strange-IDN-returned-string/td-p/2795446
https://forums.digi.com/t/unwanted-telnet-protocol-bytes/6663

The this Python library for the Rigol DP832 power supply https://github.com/kearneylackas/DP832-Python
